# How does one perform a PPA Installation

Tags: release-loki, ppa

Aloha:

How would one install the PPA:detly/mactel-utils package into (onto) elementary os (loki)?

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:detly/mactel-utils
sudo apt-get update
```

If you are missing `add-apt-repository`:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common python-software-properties
```